# how to create a survey app only allow the invited person visit only in a secure way

Tags: node.js, jwt, survey

I have one Node.js app and database is MSSQL. I have implement the basic functionality like register, login and others like adding users. The authentication of the api is using JWT, so when a user login, he will receive a token saved on the cookie, just like normal app.

I'm going to add a new survey functionality to the app. With the survey, it does not require user login and does not ask to create a new user account, but only the person receive the invitation link can visit. What I current save on the survey main table is the email address and person name going to receive the survey and one auto generated UUID. The survey link may be /survey/UUID.

How should I do it and how to secure the survey form?

What I was thinking is to create a new token for each survey use only and attchecd with the invitation link, and then validate that token. But because it does not ask the login, I cannot validate the token with email. Should I need a Recaptcha only? Or I need to the login here, or at least need to the user confirm his email address so the token can be verify?

Answer (score 0):

You could use id (primary key) AUTO increment on the main table, and 10-15 char as password. you generate token based on your format such as url/id+password. Id is always unique so its guarantee that each user will have their own token.

Comment: First of all, do you mean I should create a new table to save the password and the token generated? Second, with url/id+password, does this mean if someone else has the link, he can access the survey as well?

Comment: u can use the same table and yes anyone with link can access the survey.  Another option would be fill in email and password instead of id and password. However using id allow changes to be done later on, such as request new survey link.